# How to detect if there is any file added in a folder?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server

Is it a way to detect if there is any file added in a folder? Include the sub-folder.

For example, check if any text file `*.txt` is added in folder `c:\data-files\` or its sub-folders.

The folder can be shared folder of another machine too.

Comment: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b

Comment: FileSystemWatcher seems not work with shared folder.

Comment: Well it may *seem* not to work, but it definitely does work... You just have to know the actual path

Comment: I tried `$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher "c:\temp" "*.*" -Property ....` and it works. However, `$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher "\\remote\shared\" "*.*" -Property ....` didn't trigger the script.

Comment: I'm not sure why, it works for me. Are you able to do a `get-childitem` on `\\remote\shared`?

Comment: I forgot to re-initialize the FileSystemWatcher object. My fault.

Comment: All good. Glad you were able to get it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are confused on the types of events that are triggered:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_events(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This should work, taken from the link above and modified for your requirements:

```
#By BigTeddy 05 September 2011 

#This script uses the .NET FileSystemWatcher class to monitor file events in folder(s). 
#The advantage of this method over using WMI eventing is that this can monitor sub-folders. 
#The -Action parameter can contain any valid Powershell commands.  I have just included two for example. 
#The script can be set to a wildcard filter, and IncludeSubdirectories can be changed to $true. 
#You need not subscribe to all three types of event.  All three are shown for example. 
# Version 1.1 

$folder = '\\remote\shared' # Enter the root path you want to monitor. 
$filter = '*.txt'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here. 

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.                           
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'} 

# Here, all three events are registerd.  You need only subscribe to events that you need: 

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action { 
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 
Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green 
Out-File -FilePath c:\scripts\filechange\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}
```

Please note that once you close the powershell console the fileSystemWatcher is thrown away, and will no longer monitor the folder(s). So you have to make sure the powershell window stays open. In order to do that without it getting in your way I suggest a scheduled task http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/12/use-scheduled-tasks-to-run-powershell-commands-on-windows.aspx