# Powershell script not detecting file added to folder on network drive

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to have a PowerShell script detect when files are added to a folder on a network drive as in:

https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/05/01/monitor-windows-folder-for-new-files.aspx

[How to detect if there is any file added in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766512/how-to-detect-if-there-is-any-file-added-in-a-folder)

I modeled my script after the example in the first link, and it was working fine until I needed to restart my computer, and now it will not work. This problem also occurs on a separate computer as well.

I provide the full path to the folder on the network drive (on a NAS server) to the script using the full UNC path i.e. :

```
\\server\example\this_folder
```

The script works on folders on my local machine, i.e. the Desktop folder

Here is my code:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.Path = '\\server\example\folder1'
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -Action{

Write-Host "test"

}
```

Comment: i think drive maps are _per account_ ... so, are those two lists for the same account? also, i suspect that elevated maps would also be limited to the elevated state. i cannot prove that, tho.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you're right about that, I ran net-use in a non-admin powershell window and the lists matched up.  But, running the script as non-admin didn't fix anything.

Comment: you likely otta add that info to your Question. [*grin*] also, since it makes no difference, i would consider removing that entire section as it distracts from the actual problem. ///// i cannot test using filewatcher across a net connection since my NAS is down. i will go back to lurking ... good luck!

Comment: Good point. Done! And, thanks!

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*]